# Miniature painting - what does it mean to seal the model?

Tags: miniatures, modelling

I was watching a couple of miniature painting tutorials and both times the narrator referred to "sealing" the model.  I'm not quite sure what he meant by this.  What does sealing a model refer to?

Comment: I think this is of topic

Comment: @Andrey Actually, according to the [FAQ](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/faq#questions), the preparation of wargame miniatures is considered on-topic.

Comment: @Johno i was following this thread, http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/9/is-this-site-also-good-for-miniature-wargames-questions  which looks to be older than the faq.  My mistake

Comment: Yup, the consensus was to not branch away from the existing platform for this discussion.  I read that meta thread before posting :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sealing a model means applying a coat of a transparent and durable protective layer after painting. Normally this is a clear varnish. After leaving your painted model to thoroughly dry, you brush or spray it on. This helps prevent chipping and flaking of your paint job during subsequent transportation and gaming.

You have a basic choice of gloss or matte finish, depending on whether you like your models more reflective or not.

The main downside of sealing is that it makes applying further paint changes or touch ups very difficult. So be sure you're satisfied with your paint job before you seal!

Comment: I strongly disagree on your last point, unless you're using WAY too much varnish doing an additional touchup later shouldn't be a big deal (though you'll probably want another layer of sealant.

If you use a spray varnish you do want to avoid doing so when the humidity is high (also preferably test on a spare piece of sprue to make sure there aren't any issues).